# Expose port does not work in docker

Tags: angularjs, docker, dockerfile

I have this image

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update  && \
    apt-get install -y curl vim && \
    curl -sL "https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x" | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs net-tools git && \
    npm install -g @angular/cli

EXPOSE 4200

WORKDIR /ng_app/jwt-auth

ENTRYPOINT ng serve
```

I run it with

```
docker run -it -v `pwd`:/ng_app -d -p 4200:4200 --name ang_cli ang_cli
```

The log is this one

```
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost: 4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
 3
Date: 2018-05-08T21:47:18.204Z
Hash: 993ee08f65694a2dd3c9
Time: 10559ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 10.6 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 227 kB 
[initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 5.4 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 15.6 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 3.37 MB [initial] [rendered]
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

But localhost:4200 **does not show anything**.

I created an empty app with `ng new jwt-auth`

I already tried

```
--expose
--net host
```

But with no luck.

Comment: Did you try to curl / telnet to 4200 from the container itself ?

Comment: The output was `curl http://localhost:4200`
`curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

Comment: I would have similar thoughts to @SimoneZabberoni here. Are you running Docker through a VM or on the host directly? If you're running Docker through a VM (e.g. as is done in Docker for Mac and Docker for Windows) then you will need to get the VM's network address to access the container through its exposed port.

Comment: So the issue is not in the 4200:4200 mapping, but on the containerized app. Do you see anything in the live logs ?

Comment: Just what I have posted Simone

Comment: I am using docker for mac Mike

Comment: `-v \`pwd\`:/ng_app` or `-v $(pwd):/ng_app`?

Comment: I tried both Federkun but same result.

Comment: If curl returns "Empty reply from server"  both from the container and an external machine pointed to the docker host:4200, the issue should be on the app.

Comment: Even if it is an empty app created with ng new. I didn't add any code yet. Simone

Comment: we are assuming that `curl http://localhost:4200` was ran inside the container. since you're on mac you're probably using `docker-machine` or something similar to that, so the correct url for you will be something like `curl http://$(docker-machine ip default):4200` - please focus on get a response from inside the container first. Can you confirm it before thinking of something else?

Comment: I ran curl in my mac

Comment: please run it inside the docker container itself, to confirm that the application is running okay.

Comment: Yes, as me and @federkun suggested, run curl from the container

Comment: after run `curl http://$(docker-machine ip default):4200` `Docker machine "default" does not exist. Use "docker-machine ls" to list machines. Use "docker-machine create" to add a new one.
curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

Comment: This is the output inside the container `root@ab13ff1e4ce0:/ng_app/jwt-auth# curl http://localhost:4200
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JwtAuth</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>


<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" s...`

Comment: marvellous, `docker-machine ls` then replace `default` with the correct one.

Comment: docker-machine ls returns empty `docker-machine ls
NAME   ACTIVE   DRIVER   STATE   URL   SWARM   DOCKER   ERRORS`

Comment: where are you running docker?

Comment: locally in my mac. Version 18.03.1-ce-mac65 (24312)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue should be here:

```
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost: 4200
```

That's the **container**'s localhost, so port 4200 will be unavailable for the docker host as well any other machine using the mapped 4200.

You should run ng with 0.0.0.0 binding:

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

and the mapping should work.